# AWS SNS Ruby SDK can't subscribe an endpoint to an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-sns

The Ruby SDK is a little confusing, as the docs have two methods for subscribing.  One is deprecated now I believe [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/SNS/Client.html#subscribe-instance_method).

[image: Class: AWS::SNS::Client]

The other is the intended method as it says in the source code:

    `# To create a subscription, use the {Topic#subscribe} method.`

But in the code it's pointing to, the passed in options go through a filtering process that don't allow me to specify the `application` protocol.

def endpoint_opts(endpoint, opts = {})

```
    case
    when endpoint.is_a?(SQS::Queue)

      # auto add a policy to the queue to allow the topic
      # to send the queue messages
      unless opts[:update_policy] == false
        policy = endpoint.policy || SQS::Policy.new
        policy.allow(
          :principal => :any,
          :actions => [:send_message],
          :resources => [endpoint]
        ).where(:source_arn).is(arn)
        endpoint.policy = policy
      end

      { :protocol => 'sqs', :endpoint => endpoint.arn }

    when endpoint =~ /^arn:/

      ################################################# 
      THIS IS WHAT FILTERS IT, I get this error
      ################################################# 
      raise ArgumentError, "expected a queue ARN" unless
        endpoint =~ /^arn:aws(.*?):sqs:/
      { :protocol => "sqs", :endpoint => endpoint }
    when endpoint.kind_of?(URI)
      { :protocol => endpoint.scheme,
        :endpoint => endpoint.to_s }
    when endpoint =~ /^(https?):/
      { :protocol => $1, :endpoint => endpoint }
    when endpoint.include?("@")
      { :protocol => opts[:json] ? "email-json" : "email",
        :endpoint => endpoint }
    when endpoint.gsub(/\D/,'') =~ /\d{11,15}/
      { :protocol => "sms", :endpoint => endpoint.gsub(/\D/,'') }
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "could not determine protocol for '#{endpoint}'"
    end
  end
```

[and the documentation also doesn't list a way to do it, as it lists all protocols other than through an application.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html)

So... It looks like the the `application` protocol option is purposely filtered, or someone isn't writing very good tests :)
Is there any way to use the AWS SDK to subscribe endpoints from an application to a Topic?  Am I missing something big here?  Please help!